# How to select a specific table from a pptx (XSLFTable table in .pptx presentation) file?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

In my .pptx file I have multiple slides. Each slide has multiple tables on the same page. I wrote the following code through which I can select text in all the tables at the same time. But I want to select a specific table using `Apache POI`

```
for(XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()){
                for(XSLFShape shape : slide){
                    if(shape instanceof XSLFTable) {
                       t = (XSLFTable) shape;
                       t.getCell(1, 1).getFillColor();
                       System.out.println(t.getCell(1, 1).setText("This is what I wrote!!"));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you want to select a specific table, then this table must be specifiable by somewhat. For example the n-th table you could get using a counter in the for each loop which counts up each time a `instanceof XSLFTable` was found. Or you could specify the table by some text in a special cell in it. To do so get the tables one after another with the for each loop, get the text from the special cell, compare the text with the searched text and if it equals, you have the right table.

Comment: found the solution and thanks anyways :)